# WHERE and JOIN in EE Add-on Dev

Tags: add-on, mysql, dashee

I'm trying to get my EE add-on (using Dashee) to get entries from the DB.

So far I have

```
    $this->_EE->db->select('ct.channel_id, ct.title, ct.entry_date, ct.status, cd.field_id_52, cd.field_id_67, cd.field_id_73');
    $this->_EE->db->from('channel_titles AS ct, channel_data AS cd');
    $this->_EE->db->where('ct.channel_id', $settings->channel_id);
    $this->_EE->db->order_by('entry_date DESC');
    $this->_EE->db->limit($settings->limit);
    $entries = $this->_EE->db->get();
```

Which works, but when it outputs I get 4 entries, when really there should only be 1. But the overall total of entries on my site is 4.

What I think is happening is

```
$this->_EE->db->where('ct.channel_id', $settings->channel_id);
```

Is not selecting the correct channel, but not sure why.

Settings are set like this:

```
        $this->settings = array(
            'title' => 'Recent Orders',
            'channel_id' => '6',
            'limit' => '10',
            'field_firstname' => 'orders_firstname',
            'field_surname' => 'orders_surname',
            'field_total' => 'orders_total',
            'custom_url' => '10',
            'status' => 'Processing'
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using 'join'

```
        $entries = $this->_EE->db->select('ct.entry_id AS entry_id,
                                           ct.channel_id AS channel_id, 
                                           ct.title AS title, 
                                           ct.entry_date AS entry_date, 
                                           ct.status AS status, 
                                           cd.field_id_52 AS total, 
                                           cd.field_id_67 AS first_name, 
                                           cd.field_id_73 AS surname')
                                 ->from('channel_titles ct')
                                 ->join('channel_data cd','ct.entry_id = cd.entry_id', 'inner')
                                 ->where('ct.channel_id', $channel_id)
                                 ->order_by('ct.entry_date DESC')
                                 ->limit($settings->limit)
                                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a proper API for this. Take a look at Channel Data. I made it so that it would solve this exact problem, as I grew tired of writing hard to maintain code, and one with hardcoded id's.

In Channel Data, you would do the following:

```
$entries = $this->EE->channel_data->get_channel_entries($channel_id, array(
    'where' => array(
        'channel_titles.channel_id' => $this->settings->channel_id
    ),
    'order_by' => 'entry_date'
));
```

*This would return an Active Record object the same as the `$this->EE->db->get()` method*.

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Channel-Data

While there is nothing wrong with other solution, Channel Data can provide a more abstract approach that can be easier to maintain in the long run if the fields ever were to change.